# How do swift alchemy, toxicologist and Master Alchemist interact?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

The [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) archetype [eldritch poisoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/eldritch-poisoner-alchemist-archetype) gets the class feature toxicology, which halves the time it takes to create poisons. I'm assuming this stacks with the alchemist's class feature [swift alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Swift-Alchemy-Ex-) which *also* halves the time it takes to create poisons and alchemical items.

A level 3 poisoner has a Craft (alchemy) bonus of +18 and the feat [Master Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-alchemist). How fast can he make a dose of the poison [gray justice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/gray-justice)?

Comment: I've just been asking [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83188/4173), I hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. The original question said the alchemist's Craft (alchemy) skill check was +18, but the math only seemed to work out to +15 (this is kind of a big deal as my answer below shows). When I edited the question, I stuck with +18 but you might want to check your character sheet. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply :) just so you know, the number I had worked out was 3 ranks plus 3 class skill, another 3 from class feature plus an additional 2 from toxicologist, plus 5 from 20 int and 2 from skill focus

Answer (score 1):

#### Normal speed…

Assuming consistent [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) (alchemy) skill check results of 28, an [eldritch poisoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/eldritch-poisoner-alchemist-archetype) [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) that possesses a Craft (alchemy) skill bonus of +18 completes 504 sp of progress on a 4,000-sp dose of [gray justice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/gray-justice) each 1/4 day, completing a dose in 8 days. If the GM allows this alchemist to make multiple Craft skill checks in a day, the alchemist can complete the dose of gray justice in but 2 days. (This progress is determined by taking 28 (the check's result) × 18 (the Craft (alchemy) skill check DC of the poison gray justice) = 504 sp.)

#### …Accelerating…

Were this alchemist confident or if the GM allows this alchemist to take 10 on this Craft (alchemy) skill check, the alchemist can accelerate this crafting time, adding +10 to the DC therefore making the Craft (alchemy) skill check DC 28 for the 4,000-sp dose of gray justice. That alchemist then completes 784 sp of progress on the dose of gray justice each 1/4 day, completing a dose in 6 days. If the GM allows this alchemist to make multiple Craft skill checks in a day, the alchemist can complete the dose in but 1 1/2 days. (This progress is determined by taking 28 (the check's result) × 28 (the accelerated Craft (alchemy) skill check DC of the poison gray justice) = 784 sp.)

#### …And full throttle with the feat [Master Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-alchemist)

The feat [Master Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-alchemist) makes this *far* faster. Such an alchemist can create a dose of gray justice in 1/4 of day even *without* accelerated crafting, the feat Master Alchemist making the poison's virtual cost (for the purposes of its time to create *only*) a mere 400 sp.

---

#### Notes

- The [*Advanced Player's Guide* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn) contains [this brief exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9ndc):

  > **For the purposes of an alchemist's class abilities, are poisons considered alchemical items?**
  >   Yes.

  Thus the alchemist's extraordinary ability [swift alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Swift-Alchemy-Ex-) applies to poisons.
- Unlike [*D&D 3.5*](http://dndsrd.net/basics.html#multiplying) which differentiates between real-word and in-game units, *Pathfinder* simply never uses real-world [multiplying](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/gettingStarted.html#multiplying) on rolls, and time needed to Craft isn't a roll. The combination of the extraordinary abilities [swift alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Swift-Alchemy-Ex-) and [toxicology](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/eldritch-poisoner-alchemist-archetype) reduces the time to 1/4.
- The GM may mandate a creature can't make more than 1 Craft skill check per day. Try to persuade such a GM to change his mind.

Comment: Master Alchemist takes it one step further than that, even - making intmod doses in that time period, rather than just one.  Admittedly, that does go a bit beyond the scope of the question as presented.